# How to configure apache web server to deploy laravel 5

Tags: php, apache

I would like to serve my Laravel application on my local apache web server. However, I am having issues.

To test if the application I made would work on an apache server, I have created a new very simple application which contains two routes.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function() {
    Route::get('/', function() { return view('myview'); });
    Route::get('/link', function() { return view('myotherview'); });
});
```

When I enter my `public` directory from my browser, it works fine, it connects to the `/` route. But when I give a link to the other route (`/link`), and try enter that route, it gives me 404 not found the error. Here is the link I give in my `myview` view to reaching `/link` route:

```
<a href="{{ url('/link') }}">Go</a>
```

When I show the source of the page, the above line is rendered as `localhost/mylaravelapp/public/link`.

I have researched this issue on the internet and there are a couple of suggestions on enabling apache mod_rewrite. I have also done that by typing `a2enmod mod_rewrite`. However this isn't seemed to be working, getting the same result. How can I solve this issue?

My laravel version is 5.2, apache 2.4.7 and I am using xubuntu 14.04.

Comment: What folder is your apache config pointing to?

Comment: have done any modifications to .htaccess file after downloading laravel? If yes, please post it here. If no, then nevermind.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is the usual configuration that works for me (same OS, Apache and Laravel version as you have).
Edit the apache2 config file (it should be under `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`), adding this:

```
Alias /yourdir /var/www/html/yourdir/public/
<Directory "/var/www/html/yourdir/public">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
```

Where "yourdir" is obviously your folder under the `/var/www/html` path. Restart your server after you modified the config file

`sudo service apache2 restart`

Now your `public/.htaccess`  should be something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /yourdir/

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Authorization Headers
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Not sure how `Order allow,deny` / `allow from all` could work in Apache 2.4 since those directives were removed in 2.2. Those lines should be replaced with `Require all granted`. ([reference](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html))

Comment: So the /yourdir folder would be `/var/www/html/yourdir`?  I feel like it would be a lot less confusing if this example was a little bit more specific.  I'm sitting here wondering if you didn't just write out the path due to laziness or if I dont' understand what you mean when you say "your folder under the `/var/www/html` path".  This example isn't working for me either, so I'm not sure I understood it correctly.  Should the `DocumentRoot` be left as `/var/www/html`?

Comment: What if the app is hosted on port `8000` such as a REST api