# NotFoundHttpException Only for the CSS and JS files

Tags: php, laravel, caching, apache2

So for context, the application is a portal for my company that we have hosted on the main production server. Then we have the developer version on a different server. Same exact application but on a different VM and has a different url. That was all set up before I got put in charge of it. Now we want to make an alpha server as the dev server can affect the main database. So for the alpha we need to pretty much have it be exactly like dev, but once it's built, copy the database to a separate db and disconnect it from the main one.

But right now the issue is setting it up. I got Apache2 setup and the site all put together. Now the issue I'm running into is that it's showing the site but not running any of the CSS or JS. The laravel log shows this:

> [2019-02-20 11:33:51] local.ERROR: User: test  Route:
>   https://test/app/portal/final.css  File: 
>   /var/www/laravel/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php  Line:  8335
>
> Class:
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException
>
> Exception: exception
>   'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException' in
>   /var/www/laravel/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php:8335

The same error comes up for the js file but I don't want to post that as it is the exact same error.

And the output of my site right now is just a bunch of links and text in a left tabbed column on the left.

I assume this is due to something not being installed or a config file not reading properly. The code for the site is all just git fetched so it's exactly the same as from the other two servers. The only difference is packages installed into the actual server. It seems that the css and js files aren't loading for some reason. I tried a bunch of other threads and fixes with no luck.

PHP Version is PHP 5.6.40-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli)
Apache2 for the server.
Composer version 1.5.6
Laravel 5

Thank you for any help.

Apache Config: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1im9voo0xqlyuf48gX-JJsRu00f0ym1UX

The CSS and JS files are in the public folder under css and js folders respectively.

Like I said, everything works just fine on the two servers already in place and the filesystem and code is the exact same at this point. The only thing that can be different is apache, laravel, and php.

Comment: The stacktrace is not helpful. The apache config would be helpful as well as a listing of where in the filesystem you are keeping the assets (css & js files).

Comment: @peter updated the main post.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Laravel mix with version ? If so, you need to import the css like :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" src="{{mix('final.css')}}">
```

or use the `asset` function just to be safe for any CSS/JS you need to import.

Comment: I'm going to say no considering if that were the case, that would already be included in the other servers code. Like I said, the other servers are working properly and the code is the exact same across all 3. So it's either an apache file or a missing package in php or composer

Comment: weird routing problem can occur, but if you use those Laravel Helper functions, they will still work, but safer.

Comment: also, take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35501041/how-to-configure-apache-web-server-to-deploy-laravel-5

Answer (score 0):

Three possibilities...

### Apache root folder

First, the document root in your apache config (or site-enabled) needs to be the `/public` folder.   In which case your request wouldn't hit the .htaccess and redirect to index.php and you'd get a bad route error. So this is a less likely option.

### Compile Your .css and .js

You haven't compiled the .css and .js using Webpack (or gulp or whatever if you don't webpack) on the new server. In this case, the .htacess would send the request to index.php and Laravel would look for a route (which is what your error looks like) and then you'd get an error about an invalid route.  Note the .css and .js should be in the `.gitignore` if you use git to clone the project, making this an easy thing to overlook and to have happen.  Nice thing is that if node and npm are setup and you use webpack, it should just be a:

```
npm run development
```

The sad thing is getting node and npm and webpack all working isn't always as simple as it should because of versions and such.

### Missing or not reading the .htaccess

Finally, your .htaccess isn't being read or didn't get copied over, which would mean that that / route would magically work, but any other routes wouldn't...  Though, in that case your .css and .js should still work -- but not likely.

Comment: So looking into it, the node and npm are extremely different versions. On the new server the versions are:

Node: v8.10.0

NPM: 3.5.2

On the old server:

Node: v0.10.29

NPM: 1.4.21

I can't seem to find a ppa for the old versions of these two installs. I tried running the development for npm and it errored out so I think it is a version error.