# Laravel dynamic Routes still accessbile with index.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes

I have been facing this issue for quite some time now on all Laravel sites I have built, i discovered that my site routes are still accessible when i appened index.php segment to it, example when I visit my site using this link - https://alawi.ng/how-it-works the link is some how also accessible when i prepend index.php before the route name Example https://alawi.ng/index.php/how-it-works. tho this issue does not seems to be any big deal, it has effect on my site SEO ranking, causing duplicate route or content, please i need help.

Here is what i have in my sites .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]


    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRACE
    RewriteRule ^ - [F]
    <Files .env>
        order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    </Files>
</IfModule>
```

Here is what i have in my web.config file

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I want a situation where by it either redirects the user to the actual URL removing the index.php from it -  so when a user try to access https://alawi.ng/index.php/how-it-works they get redirect to https://alawi.ng/how-it-works if such route exists, and if it doesn't to a 404 page which i have already created.

PS: i am using linux server, shared host, and have set the storage folder to 775.

Thank you.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35501041/how-to-configure-apache-web-server-to-deploy-laravel-5

Comment: Hello. Can u help me with my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO this is only a problem if Google knows about the URLs containing `index.php`, which it probably doesn't.

If you want to be on the safe side, you can:

- add [a canonical meta tag](https://yoast.com/rel-canonical/) to your template, pointing to the URL without `index.php`.
- add these lines to your .htaccess file, just below `RewriteEngine on`:

```
    # Remove 'index.php'
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/?(.*)?$ /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

This configuration will remove `index.php` from all URLs and redirect the user.