# Laravel route mapping problem: can not map an url to a controller method

Tags: php, laravel

I have a laravel project served by apache and located in the apache root folder and accessed at http://hostname/foo and I have troubles to map an url to a controller method. The following is the controller with the method (simplified for the purpose of illustration).

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ShowController extends Controller
{
    public function show($id)
    {
        return 'show: ' . $id;
    }
}
```

The following is the route mapping in routes/web.php

```
Route::get('show/{id}', 'ShowController@show');
```

The trouble is that the url like the following doesn't work.

```
http://hostname/foo/show/1
```

The above url got me to phpinfo().  But the following url gave the expected result.

```
http://hostname/foo/public/show/1
```

The following mappings don't work either.

```
Route::get('/show/{id}', 'ShowController@show'); // with a leading slash
Route::get('show/{id}', 'ShowController@show')->name('show');
Route::get('/show/{id}', 'ShowController@show')->name('show'); // with a leading slash
```

I appreciate any info or suggestion. Thanks. My php is 7.1.

Comment: It seems to me like you're serving the root folder of your Laravel project instead of the public folder? I may be wrong

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my post with the info that my project is served by apache and it's under the apache root folder.  So my question is: is the mapping relative to the project root (i.e. /foo) or to the public folder (i.e. /foo/public)? Is there any difference with or without the leading slash?

Comment: It is relative to the public folder, no matter you use the leading slash or not. There's no difference on that from what I know.

Answer (score 1):

This entry point of Laravel will always be `/public`.

You can find how configure Apache here :
[How to configure apache web server to deploy laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35501041/how-to-configure-apache-web-server-to-deploy-laravel-5)

Answer (score 1):

The project should be served from the `public` folder.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you use something like xamp, wamp... I recommend not using theses but launch the server with `php artisan serve`. This way, you could access your website on localhost:8000 by default.

Comment: Actually I serve the project with apache.  The project (foo) is under the apache root folder.  I'll add the info in my post.  thanks.