# Laravel 8 and running on the server

Tags: javascript, css, laravel-8

I have a problem with running Laravel 8 on the production server.

In the root directory I put the .httpacces file from the public directory and changed the name of the server.php file to index.php

Everything works except styles, js, and more

The contents of the .httpacces file


Options -MultiViews -Indexes

```
RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

What do I have to change, add? Thank you very much for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

You do *not* want to rename the server.php. Whether you are using Apache or nginx, make sure your Documents Root points to the `public`!! folder of your Laravel application. Never point it to the main directory. You can find configurations for nginx and apache online regarding laravel.

Comment: as I have in this .htaccess file, I have to change to the main directory on / public

Comment: Which server are you using? Apache, Nginx or anything else?

Comment: I use Apache.....

Comment: You can have a look at this answer: [Apache with Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35501156/11271671)