# How can I add index.php hiddenly on laravel?

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-8, hide, public

When I visit
--> website.com
its working fine.

But when I visit
--> website.com/page
its not working

Note that, If I visit
-->website.com/index.php/page its working fine.

So I want to add index.php in all pages but hiddenly. Because I don't want to see index.php in the pages.

here is my htaccess --->

Options -MultiViews -Indexes

```
RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

```
<Files .env>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: check the problem here https://www.upclerks.com/ , https://www.upclerks.com/service

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35501156/559465